# Create a base map of a one country in Folium

Tags: python, leaflet, gis, geopandas, folium

I'm trying to create a basemap of the UK in folium.

I don't want any other countries visible when I zoom out.

I have tried it with a zoom level, but other countries are visible:

```
import folium

uk_map = folium.Map(location=[51.5, 0.127], zoom_start=15, tiles='CartoDB positron')
```

Comment: If you disable the pan and zoom functions and use Folium's `fit_bounds()`, you can display only the selected rectangular area. I think this is close to your goal.

Comment: As an alternative, if you have Geojson data for the UK only, you can colorize only that region.